# Matplotlib: Get Rid of White Border

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I want to get rid of the white border when I save my image to a png in python.

I tried `plt.box(on=None)`, `plt.axis('off')`. I tried setting the figure's `'frameon`'  parameter to false.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure


figure(num=None, figsize=(7.965,7.965), dpi=80,facecolor='none',clear=True)
plt.box(on=None)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(Data, cmap='Greys_r', norm=Norm,origin='lower',aspect='auto',interpolation='nearest')

plt.savefig(locationFITSfolder+fitsFile[:-5],transparent=False,bbox=False)
```

I want there to be no white border to my image. Transparent.

Comment: Did you tried https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the parameters to the `savefig` function, you will get the desired output.

Specifically, you must use `transparent=True`. Note that `bbox=False` and `frameon=False` are optional, and only change the width of transparent space around your image.

Adapting from your sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

#create sample data
import numpy as np
Data = np.random.random([4,4])


figure(num=None, figsize=(7.965,7.965), dpi=80,facecolor='none',clear=True)
plt.box(on=None)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(Data, cmap='Greys_r',origin='lower',aspect='auto',interpolation='nearest')

plt.savefig(locationFITSfolder+fitsFile[:-5],transparent=True)
```

(sidenote -- you may wish to use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html), .split, and .splitext for file I/O, instead of slicing string names)

This yields the expected image output: [image: test image] (note that the image has transparent borders when you open it in a new tab or download it).